# SwiftUI chart animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, charts, swiftui

I want to do a chart animation of where 2 paths present each other from left to right. I have the following code:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
            let height = geometry.size.height
            let width = geometry.size.width

            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -height * self.ratio(for: 0)))

                for index in 1..<dataPoints.count {
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(
                        x: CGFloat(index) * width / CGFloat(dataPoints.count - 1),
                        y: -height * self.ratio(for: index)))
                }
            }
            .trim(from: 0, to: end)
            .stroke(Color.accentColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineJoin: .round))
            .animation(.linear(duration: 2))
            .onAppear(perform: {
                end = 1
            })
        }
```

[image]

The animation is trimming from left to right which looks good. Problem is the starting point of Path. The chart moves from "behind the scenes" top-left position. I don't know how to set this before the animation starts. If I create a var `path: Path` how do I initialise with, e.g., CGRect if this is inside a subview and I just the width and height inside the GeometryReader ViewBuilder? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I was suspicious on the timing of rendering the screen of the .onAppear closure. I got it working using DispatchQueue. Solution:

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        end = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: A short video or gif of this would better help us understand the problem.

Comment: Just added a gif. thank you! Btw I was doing another simple animation with a rotation effect it happens the same. When I enter in the screen it slows down and the image comes from the top left to position it in the right place and then if I tap a button I update isRotated to start the animation. ```Image("ball").rotationEffect(.degrees(isRotated ? 1500 : 0)).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 3))```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line:
`-height * self.ratio(for: index)))`

I don't know what you `self.ratio(for:)` func does, and I don't understand why you use `-height` ... this seems to lead to the line starting at the upper left corner of your view. As points are added the view grows larger into negative values and gets pushed down.

You should instead start at y: height (of GeometryReader) and grow smaller but not negative.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var end = 0.0
    
    let dataPoints: [Double] = [3, 4, 7, 17, 11, 15, 4]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                let height = geometry.size.height
                let width = geometry.size.width
                
                let maxValue = dataPoints.max(by: <) ?? 1
                
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(
                        x: 0,
                        y: height - dataPoints[0] / maxValue * height ) )
                    
                    for index in 1..<dataPoints.count {
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(
                            x: CGFloat(index) * width / CGFloat(dataPoints.count - 1),
                            y: height - dataPoints[index] / maxValue * height ))
                    }
                }
                .trim(from: 0, to: end)
                .stroke(Color.accentColor, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 5, lineJoin: .round))
                .animation(.linear(duration: 2), value: end)
            }
            
            Button("Start") { end = 1 }
        }
        .frame(height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's strange. The Y axis is positive from bottom-up? To me the axis goes up-down, that's why I inverted the height number, to present the points from the bottom-up . The self.ratio(for:) is the same as your calculation of ```height - dataPoints[0] / maxValue * height``` to scale the chart values to the given size view.

Comment: Self ratio is not the same actually. It's: ```private func ratio(for index: Int) -> Double {
        dataPoints[index] / highestPoint
    }``` and highest point is ```max(dataPointsA.max() ?? 0, dataPointsB.max() ?? 0)```

Comment: Yes, inverting y is right, but you have to add the height of the outer view as a start point. e.g. start by y=200 as your lowest point, then subtract the single values, which makes the point move up. Otherwise your view only grows into negative numbers – which in effect makes the view larger value by value.